# Plugin is incompatible with new build found android studio 2.3.1 udates

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

Can anybody provide me with the solution as I am trying to update my Android studio 2.2.3 to 2.3.1. While updating its shows following error and not allow me to update.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin web page clearly states on the bottom that the plugin is incompatible with Android Gradle Plugin from Android Studio above 2.2 versions.
[Android Gradle Metrics](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9198-android-gradle-metrics--pmd)

Your alternatives by the moment are:

1. Disable Android Gradle Metrics plugin (it will allow you to upgrade to Android Studio 2.3)
2. Keep Android Studio on 2.2